# Node API Architecture on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, oauth-2.0, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm making an app that will have:

- iOS and Android apps
- A web-based "dashboard" to display data gathered from the mobile apps

The app requires that end-users create an account with us (we mostly likely will NOT use Facebook/Twitter logins).

Everything is/will be hosted on AWS using EC2/RDS/S3 (All encapsulated in Elastic Beanstalk)

```
| Web Browser |  <----> | sails.js app | <-------> |actionhero.js API|

                                                        ⬆︎  
                                                        ⬆︎
| Mobile app(s) | <-------------------------------------/
```

So far, I've built most of the backing API in actionhero.js, hosted on AWS.

It made sense to me to separate the API and the web app, because there web app is only for a small subset of users -- I'd expect 50x the traffic from our mobile apps over the web app.. We could scale the API to server the mobile users without unnecessarily scaling the sails.js app.

---

**My questions are:**

1. (*biuggest unknown*) **How should I handle authentication?**   The `sails.js` app needs to be able to make requests to the API, and so do the mobile applications.

   I was looking at the `oauth2orize` node module for creating our own Auth server, but it is designed for Connect/Express, so I don't think I could leverage it in the actionhero.js-based API.

   If the solution is to create an OAuth server, am I supposed to host that on its own EC2 instance?
2. (AWS-specific question) I don't fully understand the use case for creating what AWS describes as a "worker tier" enviornment.  Would there be a reason that the API would fall into that category?
3. If I want to run a data querying and aggregation task, I would create a separate node process for that, correct?  If so, **would that background worker have to exist on its own EC2 instance?**
4. Sails.js and Actionhero.js both provide heavy support for socket.io.  Should communication between the Sails app and my API happen over a persistent WebSocket connection?  Will that scale if I need to create new instances in the future?

This seems like a fairly typical pattern; I'd like to hear if there are any big red flags in this design, *before* I paint myself into a corner.  :-)   THANKS!

**Bonus question** (specific to AWS Elastic Beanstalk)

Will I create separate "Applications" for the sails.js server and the API server? It looks like that's the only way to set it up, anyhow, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

We have used node and beanstalk for a couple of applications now. For authentication, you can create an account for the user when they first access the app, and store the account id on the device. If you want them to be able to log in from multiple devices, you'll need to provide some kind of way of them identifying themselves, which is either id/password, or using Facebook. It's not that tough to set that up. Use session to allow them to log in and stay logged in. We generally just store the user id in the session.

A worker tier is for something you want to decouple from your app, something that you want to do that you don't need to know whether it succeeded/failed. A notification server is a prime example. You send the info for the notification into an SQS queue, that then gets sent to the worker tier, that does the work. We are just trying to figure this out now.

A big aggregation process, yes, I'd take it elsewhere, so it's not eating up your production server(s). You might want to create some data aggregation ongoing, as transactions are saved, so it accumulates. Big rollups after the fact can be time consuming and fragile.

Sounds like yes, they would be seperate applications.

A good tip. We use grunt to create the zip files for the app. It's a node batch tool. We check the latest info out of SVN, clean it up by doing things like removing .svn directories, apply our configuration into the config files by doing simple string replacement, then zip up resulting output. This then gets loaded into beanstalk. This takes all the guess work and time out of actually doing a new deployment. We can get a new build up in minutes that way.

Beanstalk can be very frustrating. When it fails, it's not very good at telling you why.